# What does 'extends: ["airbnb"]' actually do in a React's eslintrc file?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Say for a React app, I have `eslint-config-airbnb` and its usual bunch of peer dependencies, and `eslint-config-prettier` and `eslint-plugin-prettier`. Is this `eslintrc.js` as basic as it gets?:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: ['airbnb', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  }
};
```

I mean I learned from [the doc](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#recommended-configuration) that extending the `plugin:prettier/recommended` would do things I would have had to do with the `eslint-config-prettier` alone. So I'm wondering the same thing with `extends: "airbnb"`, like do I need some of the stuffs [here](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#example-configuration) like

```
"parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
```

I can't seem to find this documented in the eslint-config-airbnb doc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does exactly what it says: extending the AirBnB ESLint config. By extending I mean it will copy/merge the AirBnB config to yours. Overall your understanding is correct.

If you want to know exactly what the AirBnB config does, you can look at their rule file here:

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js

The JSX snippet is already there, so no, you don't have to add it to your config anymore.

Comment: I see. Thank you!